# How do I link a ruby script to /usr/local/bin so that whenever can find it

Tags: ruby, linux, cron, whenever

I made a script, and I need `whenever` to run it via cron every `30.minutes`

Linking it with `ln -s scruffy.rb /usr/local/bin` goes fine but then this happens:

```
gilani@raspberrypi:~ $ /usr/local/bin/scruffy.rb
-bash: /usr/local/bin/scruffy.rb: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Where and how do I setup a symbolic link so that cron can run my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ln -s /absolute/path/to/scruffy.rb /usr/local/bin
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ adjust this path
```

Your original command generates a symlink called `/usr/local/bin/scruffy.rb` with a target set to `scruffy.rb`. The problem is that relative paths in symlink targets are interpreted to be relative to the directory containing the symlink, not relative to path where you run the `ln` command from. So now `/usr/local/bin/scruffy.rb` is a symlink to itself, because the relative path `scruffy.rb` interpreted to be relative to `/usr/local/bin` gives you back the symlink itself. So you've a link pointing to itself, which creates an infinite loop.

**Edit**: If you don't want to type the complete absolute path to `scruffy.rb` and you execute the `ln` from the directory that it contains it, you can simply do:

```
ln -s "$PWD/scruffy.rb" /usr/local/bin
```

as mudasobwa pointed out.

Comment: `ln -s \`pwd\`/scruffy.rb /usr/local/bin` would not require adjusting path.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yes, that's better.